# Unexpected token in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a variable named "text" in javascript and it contains following value

```
text={"text":"@RT #Olle_Carly Nuevas filtraciones del iPhone 6: así sería comparado con el Samsung Galaxy S5 y el iPhone 5S: Des... http://t.co/eRuXLS6N3M"};
```

I parsed it using

```
JSON.parse(text);
```

But it gives the following error

```
Unexpected token
```

How to solve the error..
Thanks in advance.....

Comment: `"text":` not `text=`

Comment: You sure this is JSON? The text variable contains invalid JSON. JSON structure is something given here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: You're trying to use the JSON parser on something that is clearly not JSON.

Comment: sorry...Now i edited it

Comment: That is not even JSON.

Comment: `text` holds an <del>array</del> object, not JSON. Just don't use `JSON.parse` to solve the problem.

Comment: @FelixKling...thanks for ur reply...how to parse that json array

Comment: @Reddevil: Again, it's not a "JSON array" its an object literal. You don't have to and cannot parse it because the JavaScript engine does that for you. `text` already is an **object**, just access it. If you don't know how: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties

Comment: @FelixKling:ok...but I have more text values as below  text=[
    {"text":"#Olle_Carly Nuevas filtraciones del iPhone 6: así sería comparado con el Samsung Galaxy S5 y el iPhone 5S: Des... http://t.co/eRuXLS6N3M"},
    {"text":"#ROBIN_ALVAREZ01 Nuevas filtraciones del iPhone 6: así sería comparado con el Samsung Galaxy S5 y el iPhone 5S... http://t.co/AZmKXwg9wZ"},
    {"text":"(#Dmjeferson) Nuevas filtraciones del iPhone 6: así sería comparado con el Samsung Galaxy S5 y e... http://t.co/7tpLuvhFSF (@Dmjeferson)"},

]...then how to parse it or get second or third text values

Comment: Again that seems to be an array holding objects. Just access the array and its elements. Any good JS tutorial explains how to do this, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Referring_to_Array_Elements, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties

Comment: Actually, per the latest JSON spec, this would be valid JSON: `json = '"string"';`  The problem with the original (pre-edit) JSON sample was that the string element wasn't quoted.  Literals are permitted to be valid JSON now.  But quoting rules still apply.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a javascript variable that is not compatible with JSON script.  The code should be in the format of var text = '{parameters and text}' then var obj = JSON.parse(text); then manipulate obj how you like